# How to open the web configuration of Pfsense

Tags: pfsense

I installed Pfsense on VMWare Player and I set IP adresses for wan interface and Lan interface.

[image]

When I write the adress https://192.168.40.1 on the address bar of my browser I got a time out and I could not open the web configurations.

Any idea ? 
Thank you

Comment: Make sure your local computer (where you're running the browser) is in the subnet 192.168.40.x, and/or that the LAN IP address is routable from your computer?

Comment: This address 192.168.40.1 is the address of VMNET1 host only of WMWare and My virtuale machine is connected to that network by the Network Adapter. I can ping it too in my local computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, have you tried putting the WAN address in your browser? That probably won't work though.

I think I dealt with this problem once by making an ssh tunnel to the open ssh port on the WAN address (ssh -D 8000 root@pfsense-wan-ip), then set up the browser (make localhost:8000 your browsers socks proxy) to use the tunnel  to load the web configuratator.

You could additionally probably make a second interface in VMWare that represents that LAN interface and setup NAT forwarding to allow you to connect from your desktop to the web configurator.

Lastly, I seem to remember that you can make the web configurator run on the WAN ip by editing a file somewhere.

Comment: I tried it I get the same thing, I cannot access. and as you see in the picture the OS is asking to open the LAN address.

Comment: Oh right, by default it's only bound to the LAN ip. I know windows doesn't have a native ssh client but the ssh thing totally works. I used to have a job that used virtualized pfsense to run dev environments, and that was an easy alternative to making a VPN connection to the pfsense wan (which will also work btw, its just a ton of work to setup)

Comment: Hey, I have an idea. Why don't you install another virtual machine that's a desktop, bridge it to the same virtual network as the pfsense lan, and just run the browser from the desktop vm?

Comment: I will try it ..

Comment: Hey that worked ! Thank you, I opened another virtual machine on CentOS and bridge it to the same network.